# center of the DocLayoutPanel is not rendering properly when embebed inside SimplePanel/SimpleLayoutPanel/ResizeLayoutPanel.

Tags: gwt, view, gwtp, gwt-platform

Child view has DocLayoutPanel and Want to embed it into SimplePanel. center position is ScrollView and it is not displayed properly.

position in Parent View

```
<ui:SimplePanel ui:field="plageHolderID"/>
```

layout in Child view

```
<ui:Binder>
    <g:DoclayoutPanel>
        <g:north>
        </g:north>

        <g:center>
            <g:ScrollPanel>
                <g:VerticalPanel ui:field="paneForList">
                    <!-- Display List here-->
                </g:VerticalPanel>
            </g:ScorllPanel>
        </g:center>

        <g:south>
        </g:south>
    </ui:DoclayoutPanel>
</ui:Binder>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean [DockLayoutPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html).

The issue with the center not showing correctly is caused by the [SimplePanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SimplePanel.html), which does not implement [ProvidesResize](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ProvidesResize.html).

[DockLayoutPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html) implements [RequiresResize](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RequiresResize.html) and therfore either needs to be placed in a panel, which implements [ProvidesResize](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/ProvidesResize.html), or it needs to be given a specific height by calling [setSize()](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/UIObject.html#setSize(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)).